# How to enable a Rails app to allow user customization of menu and other features? Including "app" installs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a social network for gamers. It is in Rails 4 and uses PG. How can I add an "app" to it that changes the same site, and turns it into a site for movie enthusiasts, and most importantly lets users toggle back and forth?

gameexample.com would have a certain navbar. If you wanted, you could also "install" the movieexample app. movieexample app changes the navbar menu of the site, **but keeps your other info, such as past messages, profile, interests, etc.** Since many social networks share these basic things, why change? And changing "apps" would be seamless. You just click the button/icon. Some menu items are different, and your profile options and other people's profiles now emphasize different things (instead of gaming, now it's movies you want to watch, have seen, want to make, etc.)

You could access either site by it's own URL, but they would share the same DB. No having to sign up or in to a totally diff site. And the DB saves all your messaging, friends, etc across both sites.

I am using Rails 4.0.5 and PG 9.x. Also Bootstrap 3.

What is the most efficient way to have a site link so closely to another? Even if movieexample.com goes to movies.gamingexample.com, that's fine. But preferably not. More importantly though, how do I get the menu and everything to "scope" to each site? My best guess is to do

```
if [from movieexample.com]
then display [movie stuff]
else
[display gamingstuff]
```

Is that a reasonable way, or are there better ones? There is a link on each site back to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use templates based on your domains, but it's too long to explain. Start using this guide:

http://www.justinball.com/2011/09/27/customizing-views-for-a-multi-tenant-application-using-ruby-on-rails-custom-resolvers/

Comment: Thanks! I did not know a good way to search before, but now I know that "multi-tenancy" is what I am looking for, or close enough.